# JMeter MVC Login - DXScript, DXMVCEditorsValues

Tags: java, jmeter

On recording a Login done in MVC using JMeter, following parameters are also recorded:

DXScript
DXMVCEditorsValues

These values are not available in login page. Should this be captured as a regex??

How to handle this scenario? I get Java Null Pointer Exception ...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 popular Post Proccessor to perform correlation in JMeter

1. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
2. [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Depending on how your `DXScript` and `DXMVCEditorsValues` are represented in login page source you need to consider one of options to get them, store to JMeter Variables to re-use in following requests.

Links:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions Guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [XPath Language Tutorial at w3schools](http://w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp)